# Tossing a coin. X is the number tosses. What is the probability that X is an odd number?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

**Question:**

A "fair" coin is tossed until the first time we get tails. Let $X$ be the number tosses. What is the probability that $X$ is an odd number?

**My attempt:**

So first we need to find what type of probability distribution to use. Correct me if I'm wrong:

Binomial Distribution: Not applicable here since it's for number of successes given the probability to succeed

Geometric Distribution: The "definition" doesn't really match what we're looking for.

This is where I'm stuck. I have no where to start exactly as both distributions dont seem like they would fit for this question.

I tried this with geometric distribution and have:

$$P_xk=(1-p)^{k}(p)$$

Where k is the number of trials, and p is the probability of success

$$P_xk=(1-\frac{1}{2})^{2n}(\frac{1}{2})$$

Although I'm not so sure this is the answer.

Comment: Do you mean that the number of a particular outcomes (such as tails) is odd?  The number of tosses sounds like something that would be a given.

Comment: @Crostul  Sorry while editing I must've deleted the start of the question.

Comment: Hint:  the winning paths are $\{H^{2n}T\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ and these have probabilities $\{\frac 1{2^{2n+1}}\}$.

Comment: In other words, you want to construct your answer from first principles. It might help if you drew a picture for yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the edit - makes sense now!  Can you find the probability of 1, 3, and 5?  If you see the pattern, you can use the formula for the appropriate infinite sequence.

Comment: I believe you can use $p(X=k)=(1−p)^{k−1}p$ where $p=0.5$. Then, you sum of odd $k$. Hence, $\sum_{k=1, odd}^{\infty} (1−p)^{k−1}p = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (1−p)^{2k}p$.

Comment: Almost there, now note that $\sum_{k=0}^{\inf}{a*\left(\frac{1}{r}\right)^k}=\frac{a}{1-r}$

Comment: @MikeP Thanks for your response Mike! What does the summation add to what I already have?

Comment: @MikeP that formula should be $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a r^n = \frac{a}{1-r}, |r| < 1$

Comment: ooops, yup Tnilk, my bad - RonaldB, I believe Tnilk's answer shows where that goes

Answer (score 1):

Consider the first toss. We have a $P=\frac 12$ probability that it's our only toss (and thus an odd number of tosses).

If it's heads, then for our second toss, we have $P=\frac 12$ that we get a tail, for an overall probability of $P=\frac 12 \cdot \frac 12 = \frac 14$ that we have an even number of tosses.

So *if* the game ends in the first two tosses, there's a $\frac {\frac 12}{\frac 34} = \frac 23$ chance that we have an odd number of tosses.

Now here's the key - if we keep going, then the pattern just repeats. The third and fourth tosses will provide the same results as above. What does that tell you about the overall probability?

Alternately, consider that ending on the first toss is a $\frac 12$ chance. Ending on the third toss means a result of HHT, which has a $\frac 12 \cdot \frac 12 \cdot \frac 12 = \frac 18$ chance. What about ending on the fifth toss? The seventh? The pattern may become clear as you list them out.

Answer (score 0):

We can simply sum the probabilities.

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

$$P(X = 2n +1) = P(X = 1) + P(X=3) + ... $$ 
$$ = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{2n+1}}$$
$$ = \frac{1}{2} * \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{2n}} $$
$$ = \frac{1}{2} * \frac{4}{3}$$
$$ = \frac{2}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

The probability $p$ in question satisfies
$$p={1\over2}\cdot 1+{1\over2}(1-p)\ ,$$
the reason being that we succeed if (i) the first toss is tails or (ii) the first toss is heads and we need an even number of additional tosses to obtain tails for the first time. It follows that $p={2\over3}$.